# These divs in my layout will not center. I've tried everything

Tags: html, css

I am so terrible at CSS it's funny.

I am trying to learn by copying a webpage and it is not happening for me. I've tried and deleted it 7 times in the past three days, but this time I'm so close to what I want I can't delete it.

I am only setting up the layout (before the inner elements) which is the hardest part for me.

This is what I have so far:

```css
.bod1 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 40%;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.bod2 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 20%;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
.foot {
  margin:auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: 340px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}
#logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 81px;
  width: 194px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

#tabs {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 80px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  float: right;
  color: black;
}
#tabs li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
  


<body>
  <div class="head">
    <div id="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://images.mint.com/web-client/images/mint_logo.png" alt="Mint logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li>Sign up</li>
        <li>Log in</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="bod1">
    <h1></h1> 
     </div>
  <div class="bod2"> 
    </div>
   <div class="foot">  
  </div>   
</body>
```

Comment: Describe the problem more properly, and if possible create jsfiddle

Comment: Have you tried `margin: 0 auto;` ? or `float: none;`

Comment: Pls provide fiddle

Comment: Please describe us what do you want?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't respond last night, I didn't expect a quick response and went to sleep right after posting. This place is much quicker than Reddit.

My problem was solved. Thank you all for trying!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can remove **float:left; on class=".bod1"**

```css
.head {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: purple;
  display: block;
}
.bod1 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 40%;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
.bod2 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 20%;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}
.foot {
  margin:auto;
  width: 60%;
  height: 340px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}
#logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 81px;
  width: 144px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#tabs {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  float: right;
  color: black;
}
#tabs li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
  <title> Mint > Start Here</title>

<body>
  <div class="head">
    <div id="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://images.mint.com/web-client/images/mint_logo.png" alt="Mint logo" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li>Sign up</li>
        <li>Log in</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bod1">
    <h1></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="bod2"></div>
  <div class="foot"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

please check below link i'm making it for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/fatehjagdeo/qj7guLhj/

or just replace your html with my below html:

```
<div class="head">
    <div id="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://images.mint.com/web-client/images/mint_logo.png" alt="Mint logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li>Sign up</li>
        <li>Log in</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

<div style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; overflow: hidden; clear: both; width: 334px ! important;">


  <div class="bod1">
    <h1></h1>


  </div>
  <div class="bod2" style="float:left;">

  </div>
</div>
  <div class="foot" style="clear:both;">

  </div>
</div>
  <div class="foot">

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you just want the red div which has class 'bod1' to be in the center. I adjusted its style like below

```
.bod1{
    width: 40%;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20%;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a center class for the div you want to centerd

```
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
 }

<div class="center">Div is centered</div>
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

change css to something like this: -

If you want to do something like this, for further queries comment below.

```
.bod1 {
    margin: -161px 111px;
    width: 40%;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.bod2 {
    margin: 0px 333px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: green;
    display: block;
}
```

here's your [**jsfiddle link**](https://jsfiddle.net/yashsoni789/mu8bh6cd/)